# C# How to get SslStream to ignore client cert validation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tcpclient, sslstream

We have a client that has their own PKI infrastructure and assigns private certs to use as SSL client authentication for application access to their rest APIs.

I need to be able to use a client cert with [SslStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx) and not have it choke that it is not trusted. Users will not be educated enough to know how to add CA certs to their local trusted cert store. Plus, most would not have the access to do so either.

The client application is being written in .Net 4.6.1

What do I need to do to get SslStream not to throw an exception with an locally untrusted client certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the constructor that accepts a certificate validation callback method?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145057(v=vs.110).aspx  Seems like that's what you are asking to do.

Comment: That is for the server certificate only, not client certificate. I am already using that.